# inserting data in a DateTimeField() in Django by using datetime-local

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Please, I am creating a to-do list app as my first django project.

My form is not valid because I am trying to insert DateTimeField in django using datetime-local.

I did research, I discovered I need to do a custom model so I parse the datetime-local field.

Pls guide me on how to create a custom model field.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any code to show?

Comment: The question is too broad. Please share your code and validation error message.

Comment: That is my models.py file. https://github.com/coolpythoncodes/To_Do_List_verision_1/blob/master/To_do_app/models.py